# strip in Python 3 is not "working"?

Tags: python, strip

I have the following `string`:

```
s = 'sd sdasd sas sas zxxx df xx de '
```

When I use
`s.strip('x')`I get the following result:

```
'sd sdasd sas sas zxxx df xx de '
```

Why is `strip()` not removing all `'x'` characters?

Comment: Strings are immutable. `Strip` does not modify the string but creates a new, stripped string. Edit: Oh yes, and also use `replace`, not `strip` for characters in the middle of the string.

Comment: Try `s = s.replace('x', '')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Python 3.6 documentation:

> str.strip([chars]): Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.

Which means that `s.strip('x')` removes only `x` from the start and from the end of the string (e.g. `"xxxabcxx".strip('x') == "abc"`) If you need replace characters inside string you probably want to use the `str.replace()` method.